# Translating data with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using an XSL file to transform another XML that uses Y and N values instead of true and false. How can I define once that all Y's or N's should become true or false and not have to do it in every single line where I'm accessing the original data?

Original XML:

```
<whatever>
 <water>N</water>
 <electricity>Y</electricity>
 <internet>Y</internet>
</whatever>
```

XSL, right now I have to translate every single time the Y to true:

```
<whatever>
 <water><!-- xsl translation here --></water>
 <electricity><!-- xsl translation here --></electricity>
 <internet><!-- xsl translation here --></internet>
</whatever>
```

Ideal XSL:

```
<whatever>
 <!-- Something magic that will automatically change all value-of output-->
 <water><xsl:value-of select="//water"/></water>
 <electricity><xsl:value-of select="//electricity"/></electricity>
 <internet><xsl:value-of select="//internet"/></internet>
</whatever>
```

Output:

```
<whatever>
 <water>false</water>
 <electricity>true</electricity>
 <internet>true</internet>
</whatever>
```

Comment: *How can I translate all the instances of these values in my output without having to do each and every one of them?* Surely *all* implies *each and every one* and *each and every one* implies *all* ?  If not please clarify.

Comment: Hi,like said @HighPerformanceMark you should clarify because we could provide many way to handle this ; even non-xsl one.

Comment: Sorry, hope I've clarified it. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I still dont understand. you will need to write a xsl rule that matches y or n for each line then replace each of them by true or false. i dont understand "and not have to do it in every single line"

Comment: Is XSLT 2.0 an option for you? If so, you could define a function `isY(n)` that returns true iff the string value of `n` is `'Y'`. In any case you could use `(n = 'Y')` to yield a boolean value, depending on whether you need case insensitivity or any more complex conversion; but maybe you're trying to avoid repeating that piece of logic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really bad at this apparently. Take one more look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler, more efficient XSLT 1.0 style-sheet would be...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[.='Y']">
 <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[.='N']">
 <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

...or equivalently...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[.='Y']">true</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[.='N']">false</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an identity template to process the XML and keep the same structure.

Add a template that converts text nodes "Y" and "N" to true and false.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- put your templates here -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=".='Y'">true</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test=".='N'">false</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy/></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>

    <!-- identity templates -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For more on identity templates, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-tipxsltidentitytpl/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()[. = 'Y' or . = 'N']">
  <xsl:value-of select=". = 'Y'"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<whatever>
    <water>N</water>
    <electricity>Y</electricity>
    <internet>Y</internet>
</whatever>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<whatever>
   <water>false</water>
   <electricity>true</electricity>
   <internet>true</internet>
</whatever>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using and overriding the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. All you want in the overriding template is to output the result of the simple XPath expression `. = 'Y'`

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, here is another one, arguably even simpler: Same template but with match="text()[.=('Y','N')]" . Of course this only works with XSLT 2.0, but worth mentioning because it is not clear which version of XSLT the OP wants. I acknowledge simplicity is not the same thing as efficiency, and the set comparison is likely to be less efficient that the or operator.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, Correct. One isn't required to use an XSLT 2.0 - only solution, if they could use a solution that works both in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0.